# Regression coefficients for base 2 log transformed variables

Tags: regression, data-transformation

I need help to interpret hierarchical linear regression coefficients when the variables are transformed with base 2 log in the following two cases:

1. Only the outcome variable is transformed, no predictor is transformed
2. Both outcome variable and predictor is transformed

There have been several questions posted on natural log transformation, but I could not find one for log base 2.

Comment: HInts: log2(x) = ln(x)/ln(2), and 1 unit in the log2 scale is a doubling in the original scale.

Comment: Since the only difference between the bases is a rescaling, there's little point to re-asking what is essentially the same question over again for each logarithmic base: you already have the answers.